# Remove the padding whenever display: none;

Tags: javascript, html, css

### Picture 1

[image]

### Picture 2

[image]

```html
<form class="row" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="kAM5G4Fg3VtTOHfSrzlB2ScLrkgHhBycDvA3FQcAebnlPjvoBcIX9Txyz4NQpFaJ">
   <div class="card-content">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col s3">
            <div id="div_id_type_choice" class="input-field ">
               <div class="select-wrapper select initialized">
                  <span class="caret">▼</span><input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-16fc2fd1-3a01-3d50-5f53-bf229cc2b819" value="Total number of clients">
                  <ul id="select-options-16fc2fd1-3a01-3d50-5f53-bf229cc2b819" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" style="width: 158px; position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; display: none;">
                     <li class=""><span>Total number of clients</span></li>
                     <li class="active selected"><span>Total new loans</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>Total renewals</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>Total debit fees</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>Total brokerage fees</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>Total interest</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>Total accounts receivable</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>Total active accounts receivable</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>Total special accounts receivable</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>Total accounts loss</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>Total completed loans</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>Total terminated loans</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>Total suspended loans</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>Total delayed fees</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>Total denied fees</span></li>
                  </ul>
                  <select class="select initialized" id="id_type_choice" name="type_choice">
                     <option value="0" selected="selected">Total number of clients</option>
                     <option value="1">Total new loans</option>
                     <option value="2">Total renewals</option>
                     <option value="3">Total debit fees</option>
                     <option value="4">Total brokerage fees</option>
                     <option value="5">Total interest</option>
                     <option value="6">Total accounts receivable</option>
                     <option value="7">Total active accounts receivable</option>
                     <option value="8">Total special accounts receivable</option>
                     <option value="9">Total accounts loss</option>
                     <option value="10">Total completed loans</option>
                     <option value="11">Total terminated loans</option>
                     <option value="12">Total suspended loans</option>
                     <option value="13">Total delayed fees</option>
                     <option value="14">Total denied fees</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <label for="id_type_choice">
               Type
               </label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row test">
         <div class="col s2">
            <div id="div_id_period" class="input-field " style="display: none;">
               <div class="select-wrapper select initialized">
                  <span class="caret">▼</span><input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-af71a392-11d1-9b85-c8e6-fd7ba7833d8d" value="Per week">
                  <ul id="select-options-af71a392-11d1-9b85-c8e6-fd7ba7833d8d" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown ">
                     <li class=""><span>Per day</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>Per week</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>Per month</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>Per year</span></li>
                  </ul>
                  <select class="select initialized" id="id_period" name="period">
                     <option value="day">Per day</option>
                     <option value="week" selected="selected">Per week</option>
                     <option value="month">Per month</option>
                     <option value="year">Per year</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <label for="id_period">
               Period
               </label>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col s2">
            <div id="div_id_product_type" class="input-field " style="display: block;">
               <div class="select-wrapper select initialized">
                  <span class="caret">▼</span><input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-05598cb4-a85e-7a34-3437-514c079cb9d3" value="Regular">
                  <ul id="select-options-05598cb4-a85e-7a34-3437-514c079cb9d3" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown ">
                     <li class=""><span>Regular</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>Special</span></li>
                  </ul>
                  <select class="select initialized" id="id_product_type" name="product_type">
                     <option value="regular" selected="selected">Regular</option>
                     <option value="special">Special</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <label for="id_product_type">
               Product type
               </label>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col s4">
            <div id="div_id_from_regular_product" class="input-field ">
               <div class="select-wrapper select initialized">
                  <span class="caret">▼</span><input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-733e336a-3c29-484f-eb4e-8f0a9d21690d" value="[P-01] : Loan: 300.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 140.00 $">
                  <ul id="select-options-733e336a-3c29-484f-eb4e-8f0a9d21690d" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown ">
                     <li class=""><span>---------</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>[P-01] : Loan: 300.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 140.00 $</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>[P-02] : Loan: 400.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 185.00 $</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>[P-03] : Loan: 500.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 225.00 $</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>[P-04] : Loan: 600.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 265.00 $</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>[P-05] : Loan: 700.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 300.00 $</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>[P-06] : Loan: 800.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 335.00 $</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>[P-07] : Loan: 900.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 370.00 $</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>[P-08] : Loan: 1000.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 400.00 $</span></li>
                  </ul>
                  <select class="select initialized" id="id_from_regular_product" name="from_regular_product">
                     <option value="">---------</option>
                     <option value="1" selected="selected">[P-01] : Loan: 300.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 140.00 $</option>
                     <option value="2">[P-02] : Loan: 400.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 185.00 $</option>
                     <option value="3">[P-03] : Loan: 500.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 225.00 $</option>
                     <option value="4">[P-04] : Loan: 600.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 265.00 $</option>
                     <option value="5">[P-05] : Loan: 700.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 300.00 $</option>
                     <option value="6">[P-06] : Loan: 800.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 335.00 $</option>
                     <option value="7">[P-07] : Loan: 900.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 370.00 $</option>
                     <option value="8">[P-08] : Loan: 1000.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 400.00 $</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <label for="id_from_regular_product">
               Product
               </label>
            </div>
            <div id="div_id_from_special_product" class="input-field " style="display: none;">
               <div class="select-wrapper select initialized">
                  <span class="caret">▼</span><input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-46a25f05-4238-9a9f-9538-e0eb419d09a2" value="---------">
                  <ul id="select-options-46a25f05-4238-9a9f-9538-e0eb419d09a2" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown ">
                     <li class=""><span>---------</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>[S-01] : Loan: 500.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 170.00 $</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>[S-02] : Loan: 600.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 200.00 $</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>[S-03] : Loan: 700.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 225.00 $</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>[S-04] : Loan: 800.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 250.00 $</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>[S-05] : Loan: 900.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 280.00 $</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>[S-06] : Loan: 1000.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 300.00 $</span></li>
                  </ul>
                  <select class="select initialized" id="id_from_special_product" name="from_special_product">
                     <option value="">---------</option>
                     <option value="9">[S-01] : Loan: 500.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 170.00 $</option>
                     <option value="10">[S-02] : Loan: 600.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 200.00 $</option>
                     <option value="11">[S-03] : Loan: 700.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 225.00 $</option>
                     <option value="12">[S-04] : Loan: 800.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 250.00 $</option>
                     <option value="13">[S-05] : Loan: 900.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 280.00 $</option>
                     <option value="14">[S-06] : Loan: 1000.00 $ / Brokerage Fees : 300.00 $</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <label for="id_from_special_product">
               Product
               </label>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col s2">
            <div id="div_id_debit_frequency" class="input-field ">
               <div class="select-wrapper select initialized">
                  <span class="caret">▼</span><input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-4426e637-9e58-d48e-0b08-fd1645afbf5a" value="1 Month">
                  <ul id="select-options-4426e637-9e58-d48e-0b08-fd1645afbf5a" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown ">
                     <li class=""><span>1 Month</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>2 weeks</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>Bimonthly</span></li>
                     <li class=""><span>1 week</span></li>
                  </ul>
                  <select class="select initialized" id="id_debit_frequency" name="debit_frequency">
                     <option value="1month">1 Month</option>
                     <option value="2weeks">2 weeks</option>
                     <option value="bimonthly">Bimonthly</option>
                     <option value="1week">1 week</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <label for="id_debit_frequency">
               Debit frequency
               </label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
         <div class="right-align"><i class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn white-text waves-input-wrapper" style=""><input type="button" name="apply" value="Apply" class="waves-button-input" id="button-id-apply"></i></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

The padding is annoying here. Even if `display: none;` allows us to make the block disappears, the padding is always there. How could I remove it whenever `display: none;`? Does `flexbox` could be a good option here? I want the drop-down menu to be along the left-edge whenever they are not empty. I think it is the parent div who take this place, but I don't know how to fix it. Whenever I select an item from `Type` some bottom drop-down menus appear and other disappear, then I want the empty space to be removed completely. An example should be surely appreciated.

### formlayouts.py

```
StatisticalToolsLayout = \
        CardContent(
            Row(
                Column('type_choice', css_class="s3"),
            ),
            Row(
                Column('period', css_class="s2"),
                Column('product_type', css_class="s2"),
                Column(
                    'from_regular_product',
                    'from_special_product',
                    css_class="col s4"),
                Column('debit_frequency', css_class="s2"),
            ),
            CardAction(
                Div(
                    Button('apply', _('Apply'), css_class='waves-effect waves-light btn white-text'),
                    css_class="right-align"),
            ),
        )
```

### index.html

```
{% block content %}
<div class="row main-content">
    <div class="col s10">
        <div class="card">
            <h5>{{ form.form_title }}</h5>
            {% crispy form form.helper %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endcomment %}
```

Comment: Please post your code. Here is a resource to help ask questions [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: add your css also... check the **Run snippet** before posting

Comment: You don't need code here, just a general method to fix it. Just something I could try.

Comment: I think what you are seeing as padding is the parent div, ie, `<div class="col s2">` which remains visible.  Perhaps in your css you have given the parent a fixed width, need to see your css to suggest a solution.

Comment: This is all I got for the css. I do not have .css file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give display:none property to its parent div

Comment: I think you are right. If you could give me a relevant example, I will accept your answer.